# 62.0 == 62.0 returns false, why?

Tags: c++, casting, compare, type-conversion, static-cast

I got really annoying problem that I can't solve. I've got this code fragment:

```
LOG(INFO) << "totalTranslation: " << m_move.totalTranslation << " tileSize: " << static_cast<double>(tileSize);
if(m_move.totalTranslation >= static_cast<double>(tileSize)) {
    LOG(INFO) << "in!";
}
```

`tileSize` equals 62 (it's `int`). In a loop, I increase `m_move.totalTranslation` value. The problem is that when `m_move.totalTranslation` equals 62, it doesn't enter `if` statement. It does, however, if it's larger than 62. Look at the log that was generated:

```
I0118 15:20:11.788576  5644 GameObject.cpp:270] totalTranslation: 61.008 tileSize: 62
I0118 15:20:11.806589  5644 GameObject.cpp:270] totalTranslation: 62 tileSize: 62
I0118 15:20:11.822602  5644 GameObject.cpp:270] totalTranslation: 62.93 tileSize: 62
I0118 15:20:11.822602  5644 GameObject.cpp:272] in!
```

As you can see, `in!` is only logged when totalTranslation is larger than 62. Why? I thought it might be casting problem, but I cast this `tileSize` which is of `int` type to `double` and still no difference.

Comment: Print more digits of yout `62` values.  You are rounding for display.

Comment: I think 62 can be represented exactly, but your `totalTranslation` is actually a tiny bit less than 62 and is being rounded for the sake of printing.

Comment: change your if to `fabs(m_move.totalTranslation - static_cast<double>(tileSize))<EPSILON`, where EPSILON is very small double

Comment: Well I don't think so @sftrabbit because when `totalTranslation` is less it's displayed as correctly (`61.008`).

Comment: @dziwna - The default precision is to print 6 digits. Doubles have 15 or so decimal places of precision. That means a double precision number can be just shy of 62 but print as 62.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For comparison of equality between floating point numbers, it is preferred to see the closeness of the numbers because of the internal representation of floating point numbers in the computer. You might have to check if the numbers are in `epsilon` distance of each other.The result of equality comparison depends on the particular compiler/machine.

Maybe you could look at this for more details: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html

Answer (score 0):

Double sometime made annoying error...
It seem to be 62.0, but in reality it's 61.9999999... but when you print it, it write you 62...
Try this :

```
if (62.0 == totalTransaction + 0.01)
do something
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking for equality of two doubles, you are on a right path to spefiy the epsilon, e.g. the acceptable margin.

```
double a = 62;
double b = 62.0000000000001;
double eps = 1e-10;

if (abs(a-b) < eps) {
    cout << "match!" << endl;
}
```